# CODEIGNITER: Ajax desplegableno Region y Comuna no está funcionando

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

tengo un formulario de registro que incluye regiones y comunas desplegable. Sin embargo no es capaz de obtener la lista de las comunas luego de haber seleccionado una región.

En consola me aparece lo siguiente como respuesta:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tablas de region y comuna**

```
    |----------------------------|
    |        regiones            |
    |----------------------------|
    |        id_region           |
    |        nombre_region       |  
    |----------------------------|

    |----------------------------|
    |        comunas             |
    |----------------------------|
    |        id_comuna           |
    |        nombre_comuna       |
    |        region_id           |
    |----------------------------|
```

Aquí está mi código.

**Controller:**

```
    public function index()
    {
        //Regiones
        $data['result_region'] = $this->regiones_model->getRegiones();

        $this->load->view('interprete_registro_view',$data);

    }

    public function comunasI()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id_region');

        $this->regiones_model->getComunas($id);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 public function getRegiones() 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_regiones');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $query_result = $query->result();
        return $query_result;
    }

    public function getComunas($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->where('region_id', $id)->get('tbl_comunas');

        $cadena = "";

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $cadena .= "<option value='{$row['id_comuna']}'>{$row['nombre_comuna']}</option>";
        }

        echo $cadena;
    }
```

**View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var path = '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/';

   $(document).ready(function() {
     cargarProvincias();

     $('#regionI').change(cargarProvincias);

   });

   function cargarProvincias () {
     var cd = $('#regionI').val();

     $.get(path + 'Intreprete_registro/comunasI', {'id' : cd}, function(resp) {
       $('#comunaI').empty().html(resp);
     });
   }

</script>
        <div class="col-2">
          <label for="region">Región <span> * </span></label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">      
            <option value="" selected>- Seleccionar Región -</option>
              <?php foreach($result_region as $region):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $region->id_region;?>"><?php echo $region->nombre_region;?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
           </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
          <label for="comuna">Comuna <span> * </span></label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="comunaI" id="comunaI">
            <option>- Seleccionar Comuna -</option>"
          </select>
        </div>
```

Cualquier idea, solución o acotación es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compara la ruta de codeigniter (config/routes.php) con la de la peticion ajax que dice "Intrepete_registro/ComunaI":

```
function cargarProvincias () {
     var cd = $('#regionI').val();

     $.get(path + 'Intreprete_registro/comunasI', {'id' : cd}, function(resp) {
       $('#comunaI').empty().html(resp);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

El **error 404** es que no está encontrando la página. En el caso de ***codeigniter*** el por defecto viene con ***URI***. En tu caso, estas pasando el id por ***URL*** lo que al encontrar ***?id_region=1***, te envía ese ***error 404*** ya que el lo interpreta, de la siguiente manera comunasI/1. Una solución a este problema que tienes, es enviar los datos por $.post te dejo el Ejemplo:

> En el Jquery:

```
   function cargarProvincias () {
     var cd = $('#regionI').val();

     $.post(path + 'Intreprete_registro/comunasI', {'id' : cd}, function(resp) {
       $('#comunaI').empty().html(resp);
     });
   }
```

> En la controladora

```
public function comunasI()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $combo = $this->regiones_model->getComunas($id);
    echo $combo;
}
```

> En el modelo:

```
public function getComunas($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->where('region_id', $id)->get('tbl_comunas');

    $cadena = "";

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $cadena .= "<option value='{$row['id_comuna']}'>{$row['nombre_comuna']}</option>";
    }

    return $cadena;
}
```

Comment: Yoel Rodriguez, no funciona nada.

Comment: Hola buenos días te sigue mando el mismo error o es otro

Comment: es tu mismo tu codigo.

Comment: Lo que me.refiero es que si te esta enviando el error 404  que colocarse en la imagen ahora te voy hacer unas modificación para que pruebes

Comment: Si veremos , cual es codigo de el error 404?

Comment: El código que te esta enviando el 404 es el jquery cuando tratas de mandar la petición que no encuentra la página. No se si esto se puede pero existe alguna forma de ver como escribiste el código final

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57056/discussion-between-yoel-rodriguez-and-diego-sagredo).